# Using a list to make a contour plot of multiple values

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I'm trying to make a contour plot for multiple values of the same function.

To accomplish that, I'm doing the following:

```
lst = Table[x^2 - y^2 == i, {i, -100, 100, 10} ]

ContourPlot[lst, {x,-10,10}, {y,-10,10}]
```

But it produces an empty plot (it's blank).

However, if I paste the contents of the list into the command, i.e.,

```
ContourPlot[
 {x^2 - y^2 == -100, x^2 - y^2 == -90, x^2 - y^2 == -80, 
 x^2 - y^2 == -70, x^2 - y^2 == -60, x^2 - y^2 == -50, 
 x^2 - y^2 == -40, x^2 - y^2 == -30, x^2 - y^2 == -20, 
 x^2 - y^2 == -10, x^2 - y^2 == 0, x^2 - y^2 == 10, x^2 - y^2 == 20, 
 x^2 - y^2 == 30, x^2 - y^2 == 40, x^2 - y^2 == 50, x^2 - y^2 == 60, 
 x^2 - y^2 == 70, x^2 - y^2 == 80, x^2 - y^2 == 90, x^2 - y^2 == 100},
 {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

it works.

What's is the difference between using  `lst`, instead of the whole list within `ContourPlot[]`.

[image: Contour Plot]

Comment: If you don't need to distinguish the contours by color, there is an easier method: `ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, Contours -> Range[-100, 100, 10], ContourShading -> None]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `Evaluate` the expression.

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate@lst, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can use `x^2 - y^2` as the first argument of `ContourPlot` with the option `ContourShading -> None` (as suggested by JM in comments) and get colored contours using the form  $\{\{level_1, style_1\},\ldots\}$ for setting the option `Contours`:

```
levels = Range[-100, 100, 10];
colors = ColorData[97] /@ Range[21];

contours = Transpose[{levels, colors}]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 Contours -> contours, BaseStyle -> Thick, ContourShading -> None]
```

[image]